# Чекбоксы и скрытые названия в заголовке

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Есть 6 чекбоксов. Каждый чекбокс имеет скрытые строки. Нужно что бы в названии документа при выборе 4х определенных чекбоксов название заменялось. То есть:

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-1"><b>Модификация «М»</b>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-6"><b>ПК</b>
  <fieldset style="border:2px #a3443e solid;">
    <legend><span style="font-family:Monotype Corsiva;color:#a3443e;font-size:25px">Выберите модель</span></legend> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-2"><b>ПФП</b> Модуль проверки функционирования полиграфа <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-3"><b>АФВ</b> Модуль фото, аудио и видеорегистрации <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-4"><b>ВРТ</b> Модуль ввода рукописных текстов<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler" data-target="list-item_1-5"><b>ОПД</b> Модуль оперативной психодиагностики<br>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="id1">
  <p>
    <b>Профессиональный компьютерный полиграф «Диана-01<span class="list-item_1-6 hidden"> ПК</span><span class="list-item_1-2 hidden">, ПФП,</span>» (или эквивалент) – 1 комплект;</b>
  </p>
```

В названии: Профессиональный компьютерный полиграф «Диана-01 **В ЭТО МЕСТЕ** (или эквивалент) – 1 комплект; при нажатии на определенный чекбокс шли названия чекбоксов **через запятую, где это нужно** (могут вообще не выбрать, а могут выбрать все чекбоксы). И при выборе сразу 4х модулей (ПФП, АФВ, ВРТ и ОПД) заменялся текст на ПК+

Comment: Те если выбрано все, то должно выводиться: "Диана-01 ПК+", а при выборе от 1 до 3 должно быть "Диана-01 {1 checkbox}, {2 checkbox}, {3 checkbox}". Вопрос, что выводить когда не выбран ни 1?

Comment: Когда не выбрано не одного чекбокса. Ни чего не добавляется Диана -01 остается как и было.

Comment: При клике на чекбоксы добавляются их названия. А вот если выбрать 4 модели сразу то только тогда ПК+ должно отображаться

Comment: Jquery можно использовать?

Comment: Не желательно. Но в принципе можно, если на скрипте не выходит

Comment: Я верстку еще немного поправлю, что бы, было проще по DOM`у ходить

Comment: Что конкретно? У меня реализация под несколько шаблонов с текстом. Это только маленький кусок кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот возможное решение

```js
var fieldset = document.querySelector('fieldset');
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var target = e.target;
  if(target.tagName === 'INPUT'){
    var additionalName = document.querySelector('.additionalName');
    additionalName.innerText = "";
    
    var checkedTypes = document.querySelectorAll('.type:checked');
    checkedTypes.forEach(function(elem){
      additionalName.innerText +=" "+elem.value;
    });
    
    var checkedModels = fieldset.querySelectorAll('.model:checked');
    var models = fieldset.querySelectorAll('.model');
    if(checkedModels.length === models.length){
      additionalName.innerText +="+";
    } else {
      checkedModels.forEach(function(elem, index){
        if(index === 0){
          additionalName.innerText +=" "+elem.value;
        } else {
          additionalName.innerText +=", "+elem.value;
        }        
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler type" data-target="list-item_1-1" value="М"><b>Модификация «М»</b>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler type" data-target="list-item_1-6" value="ПК"><b>ПК</b>
  <fieldset style="border:2px #a3443e solid;">
    <legend><span style="font-family:Monotype Corsiva;color:#a3443e;font-size:25px">Выберите модель</span></legend> 
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler model" data-target="list-item_1-2" value="ПФП"><b>ПФП</b> Модуль проверки функционирования полиграфа <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler model" data-target="list-item_1-3" value="АФВ"><b>АФВ</b> Модуль фото, аудио и видеорегистрации <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler model" data-target="list-item_1-4" value="ВРТ"><b>ВРТ</b> Модуль ввода рукописных текстов<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-toggler model" data-target="list-item_1-5" value="ОПД"><b>ОПД</b> Модуль оперативной психодиагностики<br>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="id1">
  <p>
    <b>Профессиональный компьютерный полиграф «Диана-01<span class="additionalName"></span>» (или эквивалент) – 1 комплект;</b>
  </p>
```

```js
const togglers = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-toggler');

for(let checkbox of togglers) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', toggleOnChange);
}

function toggleOnChange() {
  const checkbox = this,
    checkboxTarget = checkbox.dataset.target,
    targets = document.getElementsByClassName(checkboxTarget);
    
  for(let target of targets) {
    if(checkbox.checked) {
      target.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      target.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: оо.вообще без подключения библиотеки. Все спасибо. Да, логика правильная вышла в заголовке. Спасибо.

Comment: Роман, подскажите, что-то не работает. У меня есть скрипт который скрывает строчки при чекбоксе. Может они не совместимы?

Comment: @Ирина текст при чекбоксах?

Comment: @Ирина Возможно проблема в том что я у чекбоксов удалил data-target)

Comment: мне нужен  он вот так я прячу строчки <li class="list-item_1-1 hidden">датчик кожногальванической реакции (КГР);</li> их много

Comment: @Ирина я вернул в вёрстку чекбоксам data-target="list-item_1-*". Попробуйте снова

Comment: Отлично. С 4 варианта работают. А вот М и ПК. Как сделать? Сейчас не активны.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы на одном шаблоне "М" вообще не прописывался, а на 2х других как обычно прописывался. у меня форма выбора шаблона еще <div class="select">
 <select name="items" onchange="showBlock(this.value)">
  <option value="0">Выберите полиграф </option>

Comment: @Ирина я сейчас буду очень занят. Смогу ответить вам только через несколько часов

Comment: хорошо. Буду ждать).

Comment: @Ирина элемент id1 - он общий для всех шаблонов или для каждого свой?

Comment: @Ирина рискну предположить что это должно выглядеть как-то так https://jsbin.com/hezupis/1/edit?html,js,output (если не работает, то нажмите во вкладке Output чекбокс "Auto-run JS")

Comment: id у всех разный. Чекбоксы одинаковые и название их тоже.но почти так

Comment: @Ирина ну значит вам осталось немного переделать

Comment: можете еще подсказать, как изменить скрипт, что бы при выборе моделей прописывался предлог "с". Пример. Диана - 4 М с АФК, Диана-7 ПК с АФК, АФП. Диана-7 М ПК с АФК. Когда все 4 модели выбирают и появляется "+", то не нужен это предлог

Comment: В последней строчке менять: var checkedTypes = document.querySelectorAll('.type:checked');
      checkedTypes.forEach(function(elem){
        additionalName.innerText +=" "+elem.value;
      });
Или код отдельно прописывать?

Comment: Та строчка что вы указали - относится к тем двум чекбоксам что вверху. Поэтому следует помять строчку, которая относится к моделям. То есть `additionalName.innerText += (index === 0 ? " " : ", ")+elem.value;` поменять на `additionalName.innerText += (index === 0 ? " с " : ", ")+elem.value;`

Comment: отлично, все работает как надо. Спасибо

Comment: а как дописать код скрипта, что бы при выборе модуля "М" он слитно прописывался, а не через пробел? Это касается только этого модуля, остальные модули без изменений. Пример: "Диана-4М". Этот модуль в 2х видах диана, в 4 и 7. Вот в них нужно изменить.

Comment: нужно другой класс создавать? вместо additionalName?

Comment: и еще нашла такую проблему. Допустим я выбрала полиграф со всеми модулями. А потом передумала выбрала другой полиграф. и когда открываешь 1ый выбранный полиграф опять. скрытые  строчки не схлопываются.хотя ни какие модификации не выбраны.